# Launching PHP socket through Windows Service

Tags: c#, sockets, service, yii2

I have a Yii2 application that has a CLI interface, it has a command `yii websocket/start chat` that launches the socket and COM-binded library. I need to relaunch it every hour, so I wrote a C# service for that.

Here is the part of code that supposedly should launch yii websocket:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(this.scriptPath); // scripthPath leads to yii app
var process = new Process();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = this.@phpPath; // Path to php.exe
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "yii websocket/start chat";

// this.phpProcess - used to kill this process in other function
this.phpProcess = process; 
this.phpProcess.Start();
```

Service itself works, but websocket doesn't launch. What's wrong?

I can launch this socket through cmd, and it works just fine.

Comment: out of curiosity why does it need launching every hour?

Comment: Also, have you run this service through a cmd module and debugged it?

Comment: If not, take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications and then see if anything in here helps you debug it

Comment: No, I haven't, thanks. I need to relaunch it because library (written in 00s in visual basic) is very old and isn't very stable if it works for a long time, and there is no opportuinity to fix it.

Comment: when you say there is no opportunity to fix the VB, is that because of no time allowerd, or no VB Developers, or no source code?

Comment: All of these :) Of course, the main problem is the absence of source code.

Comment: grab a download of this from Redgate, https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/index, its saved my ass a few times when doing on site support for companies where they have no source code.  It will allow you to decompile the libraries and then you can recompile it yourself with the necessary fixes in place.  It also decompiles in both vb and c#.  the only downside (sometimes) is that its not always written as originally coded so may look a little strange

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that.